# Two-point Wightman function in $\phi^4$ scalar theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, correlation-functions, greens-functions

There is a known perturbative expansion of the time-ordered 2-point correlation function $$⟨\Omega|T\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)|\Omega⟩,$$ where $|\Omega⟩$ is the vacuum of the interacting theory. What is the perturbative expansion of the corresponding 2-point Wightman function $$⟨\Omega|\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)|\Omega⟩$$ (i.e., the non-time-ordered correlation function)? I am specifically interested in $\phi^4$ theory, though this is a general question.

Comment: Have you tried going through the same derivation but changing the Feynman propagator to advanced / retarded propagators?